# onPostExecute called before doInBackground completes - Async task

Tags: android, android-asynctask

i have method like this :

```
public void extractFiles() {

    AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> extractionTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>() {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Activity.this);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Extracting Files Please wait...");
        progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        progressDialog.setProgress(0);
        progressDialog.show();
        super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String xapkFilePath = XAPKFilePath(Activity.this);
        String exportDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Android/data/"
            + Activity.this.getPackageName() + "/files/";
        File exportDirectoryFilepath = new File(exportDirectory);
        exportDirectoryFilepath.mkdirs();
        ZipHelper zhelper = new ZipHelper();


        System.out.println("In background called");
        zhelper.unzip(xapkFilePath, exportDirectoryFilepath);

        return true;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing()) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            System.out.println("progress dialog dismissed");
        }
        if (result) {
            //start intent.
        }
        }

    };
    extractionTask.execute();
    }

public class ZipHelper {

    boolean zipError = false;

    public boolean isZipError() {
    return zipError;
    }

    public void setZipError(boolean zipError) {
    this.zipError = zipError;
    }

    public void unzip(String archive, File outputDir) {
    try {
        Log.d("control", "ZipHelper.unzip() - File: " + archive);
        ZipFile zipfile = new ZipFile(archive);
        for (Enumeration e = zipfile.entries(); e.hasMoreElements();) {
        ZipEntry entry = (ZipEntry) e.nextElement();

        System.out.println("OUTPUT DIR 1*" + outputDir);
        System.out.println("ENTRY IS " + entry);

        unzipEntry(zipfile, entry, outputDir);

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("control", "ZipHelper.unzip() - Error extracting file " + archive + ": " + e);
        setZipError(true);
    }
    }

    private void unzipEntry(ZipFile zipfile, ZipEntry entry, File outputDir) throws IOException {
    if (entry.isDirectory()) {
        createDirectory(new File(outputDir, entry.getName()));
        return;
    }

    File outputFile = new File(outputDir, entry.getName());
    if (!outputFile.getParentFile().exists()) {
        createDirectory(outputFile.getParentFile());
        System.out.println("OUTPUT FILE IS " + outputFile.getParentFile());
    }

    Log.d("control", "ZipHelper.unzipEntry() - Extracting: " + entry);
    BufferedInputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(zipfile.getInputStream(entry));
    BufferedOutputStream outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(outputFile));
    try {
        IOUtils.copy(inputStream, outputStream);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("control", "ZipHelper.unzipEntry() - Error: " + e);
        setZipError(true);
    } finally {
        outputStream.close();
        inputStream.close();
    }
    }

    private void createDirectory(File dir) {
    Log.d("control", "ZipHelper.createDir() - Creating directory: " + dir.getName());
    if (!dir.exists()) {
        if (!dir.mkdirs()) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Can't create directory " + dir);
        }
    } else {
        Log.d("control", "ZipHelper.createDir() - Exists directory: " + dir.getName());
    }
    }

}
```

Here i call the method like this `extractFiles()` but what is happening is even before the doInBackground is completed that is extracting the files for which i am showing a spinner , the  onPostExecute is called and moves to next screen.

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

check your condition in doinbackground completely perform your operation or not if perform then return true,

```
zhelper.unzip(xapkFilePath, exportDirectoryFilepath);
```

Comment: i mean to say that  doinbackground returns true regular so postexecute is calling, instead of that return true when your extract operation completes.

Comment: yes i got your point but i am not getting how to do that? can you please help me?

Comment: you can check return value from   zhelper.unzip(xapkFilePath, exportDirectoryFilepath); and check its return value. And also check your   zhelper.unzip(xapkFilePath, exportDirectoryFilepath); method is not resulting exception.

Comment: No buddy not yet zhelper.unzip(xapkFilePath, exportDirectoryFilepath);  returns void

Comment: this is my point i am trying to extract 300 files so i need to indicate the user that its extracting so i am using async task

Comment: change the method make it return type and check its exception too.

Comment: then why you not using counter to check how many file has extract if its 300 hundred then return true from doin background.

Comment: ok but it varies from app to app, so thats difficult to get the count of how many files?

Comment: yeah off course it will varies you can keep total file count in global variable using some method to count no. of file and use that global variable to check condition in doinbackground.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28412/discussion-between-goofy-and-gunjan-verma)

Answer (score 0):

I solved a very similar problem by declaring both doInBackground and onPostExecute synchronized. 
(...)
protected **synchronized** Boolean doInBackground(Void... params)
 {...}

protected **synchronized** void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {...}
(...)
In my case, doInBackground() was entering first (as it should) but somehow onPostExecute() was called before doInBackground() "technically" completed (I couldnt figure out why - maybe my unzip library objects had its own threads and did not block the doInBackground() method). Synchronizing the methods solved the problem (not without performance consequences, of course)